# Update query in android.sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My app crashes in the update query with following error

```
10-26 12:35:59.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23078): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: current_Playlist.xml: , while compiling: UPDATE FileRevisionHistory SET FileRevision=? WHERE FileName=current_Playlist.xml
```

The code for updation is

```
public void updateFileRevision(FileRevision  inFileRevision) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_REVISION, inFileRevision.mRevision);
    long updatetId = database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REVISION_HISTORY, values,MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME + "=" + inFileRevision.mFileName,null);
    Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + updatetId);
```

What is wrong in my query ?

Comment: I guess, there is no column exist in the table. See the Logcat lines no such column: current_Playlist.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the filename you specify is a string, it should be inside single quotes. Try this

```
long updatetId = database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_REVISION_HISTORY, values,MySQLiteHelper.KEY_NAME + "='" +inFileRevision.mFileName+ "'",null);
```

Comment: As i meant but this approach is not very clean and not safe.

Answer (score 1):

At first i recommend to you use **placeholders** because your approach is not very clean.

So do it like this:

```
long updatetId = database.update(<tableName>, values, <column> + " = ?", 
                                 new String[] {inFileRevision.mFileName});
```

**Note:** If you want to use your approach you need to use `'` called single quotes